# Type bounds: Propagate parameter with multiple bounds

Tags: java, generics, type-bounds

Consider the following (unchangable) API:

```
interface Bar {}
class Foo {
    public static <T extends Foo & Bar> void doFoo(T param) {
         System.out.println("I shall be your ruler");
    }
}
```

Now I have written a class that accepts a general `Foo` but in case that argument is also a `Bar`, I want to execute `doFoo` additionally in some method:

```
class Holder {
    public Holder(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public void takeOverTheWorld() {
        if(this.foo instanceof Bar) {
            // Here I want to execute doFoo(), but I can't hand it over
            // because the bounds don't match
            // doFoo(this.foo);
        )
        // Enstablish my reign
    }
}
```

Example usage of the `Holder`:

```
class Yes extends Foo implements Bar {
}
// ------
Holder h = new Holder(new Yes());
h.takeOverTheWorld(); // Should print "I shall be your ruler"
```

As mentioned in the code comments, I have problems calling doFoo() in the Holder class, because no exact type is known at that time that does extend `Foo` **and** implement `Bar`, so I can't simply cast it to such a type. Is there a way to get around this without changing the interface of `Holder`, `Foo` and `Bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `doFoo` in a private helper method which introduces the right type for a cast:

```
public void takeOverTheWorld() {
    if(this.foo instanceof Bar)
        doBarFoo();
}

private <T extends Foo & Bar> void doBarFoo() {
    Foo.doFoo((T)this.foo);
}
```

You could even do this in `takeOverTheWorld` if you don't mind that the type is then part of the public interface:

```
public <T extends Foo & Bar> void takeOverTheWorld() {
    if(this.foo instanceof Bar)
        Foo.doFoo((T)this.foo);
}
```

Comment: I will remember this: Always "infer" the type via a private method if you can't do it normally, haha

Answer (score 0):

Make a generic subclass of Holder:

```
class SubHolder<T extends Foo & Bar> extends Holder {
  private T fooT;

  SubHolder(T foo) {
    super(foo);
    this.fooT = fooT;
  }

  @Override void takeOverTheWorld() {
    Foo.doFoo(fooT);
  }
}
```

Comment: This would change the interface of Holder as the class will now be generic only for doing something that nobody does have to know about other than the class. Not a very good solution in the light of encapsulation